# Making a server info bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot for a server and I want to add a command e.g. !info and it shows the server name , member count ect.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@asyncio.coroutine
def info(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.author.server
    server_name = server.name
    server_id = server.id
    server_owner = server.owner.name

    print("server name: {}"
          "server id: {}"
          "server owner: {}"
          .format(server_name, server_id, server_owner))
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
Ignoring exception in command info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cogan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cogan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\coroutines.py", line 120, in coro
    res = func(*args, **kw)
  File "c:/Users/cogan/105.py", line 34, in info
    server = ctx.message.author.server
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'
```

can someone help please .

Comment: Here's how you tackle this problem: 1. google attribute error. 2. google "Member" in the discord api 3. realized member has no "server" attribute. You're doing doing what you intend to do.

Comment: [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) has attribute [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild), not server. Read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're either using some old tutorials or referring to the old documentation. I recommend looking at more recent tutorials and using the new docs (v1.x - rewrite).

Async (v0.16.x) has been deprecated, and there have been some [major changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) since then. One of which is the [renaming of server to guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild). So you're looking for `Member.guild` instead of `Member.server`.
Another change being context is automatically passed into commands - you don't need `pass_context=True`.

---

**References:**

- [Latest docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [`Member.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild)

Answer (score 0):

So the post you made is some old outdated discord.py code which seems too complex and way too outdated. First of all in discord.py rewrite `server` has been replaced with `discord.Guild`. The following example shows a functional way of obtaining a name, id  and owner of the guild/server, all of this code can be obtained from https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild . In my case i made it to be an embed message but you can easily retranslate it to a ctx.send message with an fmt format or a print() command in console.

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def information(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed( timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

    embed.set_author(name=f"Information for the {ctx.guild.name}")

    embed.add_field(name="Guild id:", value= f"{ctx.guild.id}")

    embed.add_field(name="The guilds owner is:", value = f" {ctx.guild.owner}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**NOTE:** discord.py rewrite functions with `async` which means that everytime you define something you must put that piece of string in front of `def` when creating a new command or event.

I highly recommend that you'd take an hour at least to slowly read through the documentation to understand the strings of code and their descriptions that youre using.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, You haven't defined the **Server*** . You can do it by doing this:

````
@asyncio.coroutine
def info(ctx):
    server = ctx.guild
    server = ctx.message.author.server
    server_name = server.name
    server_id = server.id
    server_owner = server.owner.name

    print("server name: {}"
          "server id: {}"
          "server owner: {}"
          .format(server_name, server_id, server_owner))```
````